# Creating a mysql table using flask-sqlalchemy doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, macos, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a mysql table in the python interpreter with flask-sqlalchemy. I get the error

```
File "/Users/chen97me/Documents/project/instaad/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
File "/Users/chen97me/Documents/project/instaad/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chen97me/Documents/project/instaad/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/chen97me/Documents/project/instaad/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

The code I type is as follows

```py
from website import create_app, db
app = create_app()
ctx = app.app_context()
ctx.push()
db.create_all()
```

this is what is in my venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ directory which is inside of my project directory
[image: project directory]

I am running Mac OS X which according to my research might have something to do with it.

My config.py file

```
class Config:
    SECRET_KEY='123456'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='mysql:///root:mysqls@localhost/website'
```

Comment: you may have to install MySQL database server - it is not Python's module. Web page: [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)

Comment: @furas if you're referring to the basic mysql that you can run on the command line, then I do

Comment: error shows problem with `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` so it may need something more. Maybe it didn't install some "MySQL Client" library, or it is not avaliable for python.

Comment: I checked on Linux and I have installed `mysql-service`, `mysql-client` and `libmysqlclient20`